# ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted - Robot framework

Tags: javascript, automation, polymer, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework. And I am new to this. My application is a Polymer based application. In that when I am clicking an element it is showing below error,

```
    >ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="app-block"...</div> is not clickable at point (389, 339).

   Other element would receive the click: <vsim-start-page config="{{config}}" startpage="[[startpage]]" vertical="" layout=""></vsim-start-page>
```

Below things, I have already tried, but not able to find a proper solution.

```
 1. Sleep for few seconds
 2. CLick Elment At coordinates -  Working but not a good solution
 3. Execute JavaScript    document.evaluate("//*[@name='apps']/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div",document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click();
 4. Execute JavaScript    document.evaluate("//div[contains(text(),'Parts Summary
    New')]",document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

Below is the source code for the element,

```
<div flex layout vertical>

<div class="app-title" style="font-size:0.8em;text-transform: uppercase;">Pallet Register</div>

<div class="app-subtitle">Pallet Register View</div>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`ElementClickInterceptedException` usually occurs when the element is not 'clickable' so to speak. Since you have already tried giving sleep; sync related issue can be ruled out.

What you can try is:

- Check for any external container or frame/iframe within which your element is located that might be causing this issue
- By POE (process of elimination); identify till what level is the element visible and then work xpath from there. In the example you have given the div attribute `flex layout vertical` does not seem to have any value you can check if some element before and after that to see if rendering of this div is giving an issue.
- From Polymer perspective, would help to check if there are any shadow DOM objects being used; if so then do check  below:
  https://github.com/sukgu/shadow-automation-selenium